# Why $\left|\int F\varphi\right|\leq \left(\sup_{\|\varphi\|=1}\int|F\varphi|\right)\|\varphi\|$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ bounded. Why $$\left|\int_{\Omega } F\varphi\right|\leq\left(\sup_{\|\varphi\|_{L^2}=1}\int_\Omega |F\varphi| \right)\|\varphi\|_{L^2}$$

where $F$ and $\varphi$ are $L^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The functional
$$
\ell(\varphi)=\int_\Omega F\,\varphi
$$
is a continuous functional on $L^2$. Its norm (as an element of the dual of $L^2$) is defined as
$$
\|\ell\|_=\sup_{\|\phi\|_2=1}|\ell(\phi)|=\sup_{\|\phi\|_2=1}\Bigl|\int_{\Omega } F\,\varphi\,\Bigr|\le\sup_{\|\phi\|_2=1}\int_{\Omega } |F\,\varphi|,
$$
and
$$
|\ell(\phi)|\le\|\ell\|\,\|\phi\|_{L^2}.
$$

Comment: thank you. I agree that $$\|\ell\|_{L^2}\leq \|\ell\|_{(L^2)'}$$, but why $\ell(\varphi)|\leq \|\ell\|_{(L^2)'}\|\varphi\|_{L^2}$ ? where $(L^2)'$ denote the dual

Comment: The norm of a bounded linear operator $T\colon X\to Y$ between normed spaces is the infimum of the constants $C$ such that $\|T\, x\|_Y\le C\,\|x\|_X$. It is equal to the infimum of $\|T\,x\|_Y$ over $\{x\in X:\|x\|_X=1\}$.